# Invalid command 'suPHP_ConfigPath', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: php

I was migrating my site manualy and when I try to acess the site it shows a error Internal Server Error, I saw the error log and it's showing this error: Invalid command 'suPHP_ConfigPath', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

my suPHP_ConfigPath on .htacess:

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/public_html
```

Comment: _Small Warning_ suPHP is not maintained any longer and will not receive any further updates not even security patches.

Comment: Did you install the suPHP